# Ajax only working for some users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just finished building an AJAX contact form for a client and the client complains that it doesn't work. Whenever I (or anyone else, for that matter) test it it works just fine. The client claims they see "Ajax Error" as the error text. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://example.domain.com/content/contact/php/verify.php",
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,
    data: {
        captchaResponse: $("#g-recaptcha-response").val(),
        contactType: $('#contactFormType').val(),
        contactName: $('#contactFormName').val(),
        contactEmail: $('#contactFormEmail').val(),
        contactPhone: $('#contactFormPhone').val(),
        contactMessage: $('#contactFormMessage').val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // Success...
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        grecaptcha.reset();

/* This is the error the client is seeing, that no one else is */

        $('#contactErrorField').html('AJAX Error: ' + errorThrown);
        $('#contactErrorWrapper').show(0);
        $('#contactBodyOverlay').hide(0);
    }
```

All the client sees is "AJAX Error:" with no actual error text in the errorThrown variable.

Does anyone have any idea why this code might fail for my client, but appear to work fine for everyone else. I'm nervous it is something on her end, but I am loathe to blame my client before trying everything I can.

Comment: Maybe server permissions

Comment: What is the value of `textStatus`? Also, this is no way to deal with errors. A user of your website can't do anything with an `AJAX Error` so don't show it to them. Show them a nice fluffy message and report the actual problem to a developer.

Comment: Three things would be interesting at this point. 1. Which jQuery version are you using? 2. Which Browser is he using? 3. Is a cross domain request?

Comment: @HoschNok does not really matter

Comment: Also is there a way to find out if the form action was successful and just reporting error?  I'm assuming this is an insert statement to a RDB, so is the SQL insert successful?

Comment: @ Halcyon I'm not sure of the value of textStatus, I can attempt to verify. Also yes, once these issues are resolved a better error message will be displayed to the users.

Comment: @HoschNok Latest version of JQuery, Chrome (Same as me), Should all be one domain, no ssl involved.

Comment: @MakR I'm actually trying to determine this right now. The PHP form sends an email, and I suppose it is possible the mail is going through but the error is being thrown.

Comment: Never really did find the cause of this, however it is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

- You have an absolute URI in the `url` parameter
- The `errorThrown` argument is blank

The most likely explanation is that your client is visiting a subtly different URI to the one you use for your own tests (e.g. `http://` instead of `https://`) and is triggering a cross-origin request which your server is not granting permission for using CORS.

You can confirm this by getting the client to open the developer tools in their browser and looking for an error message that talks about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

This problem can be mitigated by using a relative URI (or by setting up CORS support on the server).